# recursive function debug asserion failed

Tags: c++, recursion

I try to use recursive function to output all parameters of an int type vector, it works but[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvUH5.png) there is a Debug Assertion failed occurred. please help me point out where is problem from. thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void val(vector<int>::const_iterator beg, vector<int>::const_iterator end)
{
    if (beg!=end)
        cout << *beg << endl;
    
    val((beg + 1),end);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> vec;
    while (cin >> n)
        vec.push_back(n);
    val(vec.begin(),vec.end());
        
}
```

Comment: This problem should be solved through iteration. Recursion is rarely the right answer, and it often makes things more complicated, as this question suggests.

Comment: `beg + 1` is okay, if you assume that you're dealing with a random access iterator. A much more solution would use `std::next(beg)`, which works regardless of the iterator category. Or, even simpler, `++beg`.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly right but don't call yourself recursively once you have reached the end of the vector

```
void val(vector<int>::const_iterator beg, vector<int>::const_iterator end)
{
    if (beg!=end)
    {
        cout << *beg << endl;
        val((beg + 1),end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided where the recursion should stop. You can use something like what follows

```
void val(vector<int>::const_iterator beg, vector<int>::const_iterator end)
{
    if(beg == end) return;

    cout << *beg << endl;
    val(beg + 1,end);
}
```